# How do I hide o365 sublink in SharePoint designer?

Tags: sharepoint-online

This code I used in CSS to hide o365 bar.

```
a#o365_subLink_ViewAccount {

display: none !important;

{
```

I would like advice to how I can hide inside using SP Designer 2013 which master pages would I need to edit.

Answer (score 2):

No need to edit your master page especially in SharePoint online, What should you do is to add your CSS code in CSS file and upload it to `style library` or `site assets`. then apply it to your site as the following:

- Open Site > Site Settings.
- Below Look and Feel > Click on (Master Page) or Design Manager.

[image]

- At Site Master Page Settings > Scroll down till `Alternate CSS URL`
- Check `Specify a CSS file to be used by this site and all sites that inherit from it:`
- Browse to your CSS file
- Check  `Reset all subsites to inherit this alternate CSS URL`  if you need to apply CSS for all subsites.

[image]

Comment: When I go under Master Page Gallery I don't get to see Alternate CSS URL option

Comment: Could you please check  this image It  should be collapsed as shown in image  http://blog.atwork.at/image.axd?picture=image_1777.png

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using ?

Comment: the above steps is valid for SharePoint 2013/2016 and online, could you please tell me what's your SharePoint site template ? is it team site or publishing site? if it's a team site try to enable publishing feature , don't hesitate to tell me if you still face issue

Comment: I have SharePoint Online 2013 . It is Team template. I want to know to hide o365 menu bar

Comment: okay, first enable publishing features to can find master page link as mentioned at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627257%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 then follow my steps above

Comment: SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure is it this one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56304/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-user3161390).