# Hide OneDrive tiles in app launcher

Tags: 2016

I can add  new custom tiles in the app launcher now.
[Add tiles in the app launch](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252463/add-tiles-in-the-app-launch/252466#252466)

But I can't remove the current tiles like OneDrive, sites?

Is it possible to remove such tiles?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** remove the Newsfeed, OneDrive, Sites from **custom tiles** list!

---

**Workaround**

Use the below **CSS** style to hide Newsfeed, OneDrive, Sites in App Launcher

```
#O365_AppTile_Newsfeed{display:none !important;} /* for newsfeed*/
#O365_AppTile_Documents{display:none !important;} /* for one drive*/
#O365_AppTile_Sites{display:none !important;} /* for sites */
```

[CSS-Refrence](http://How%20to%20hide%5Cremove%20One%20drive%20and%20news%20feed%20tiles%20from%20App%20launcher)

**[output]**

[image]

> **Note:** you can add the above CSS in a script editor to hide these tiles for a specific page, otherwise, you should create CSS file and attached it to the master page as mentioned at [How do I hide o365 sublink in SharePoint designer?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211990/how-do-i-hide-o365-sublink-in-sharepoint-designer/211998#211998)